# EVE-NG QEMU based nodes are not starting

Tags: qemu, cisco, esxi, aruba

Setup:Dell PowerEdge R620 128GB Ram 12 Core server.
Vmware ESXI 6.5 Based setup: 1 VM for EVE-NG: 500GB SSD + 32 GB allocated RAM.
2nd VM for Windows Server 2016: 100GB HDD + 16 GB RAM.
On Windows client, I can access the EVE-NG via Firefox and Putty. I have tried cisco Dynamips images and nodes are starting (I can telnet with putty and change config)

When I try to created nodes based on Qemu Images(Cisco, Aruba, Paloalto, etc), the nodes do not start. I have followed the guidelines for qcow2 names as well as checked multiple sources. I have also edited the node and tried to play with all possible settings.
I have reinstalled the EVE-NG on ESXi as well but the issue remains the same.

Thanks a lot for your help and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me a bit. I was using mac and struggling to get the consoles up. Posting the below steps in case it helps someone like me:

1. Shut down the VM using command shutdown -h now
2. Go to the VM settings
3. Click Advanced -> Check "Remote display over VNC"
4. Check Enable IOMMU in this virtual machine

Answer (score 3):

I finally found an answer in the EVE-NG cookbook: https://www.eve-ng.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/EVE-Comm-BOOK-1.09-2020.pdf
Page33: Step 6: IMPORTANT Open VM Settings. Set the quantity of CPUs and number of
cores per socket. Set Intel VT-x/EPT. Hardware Virtualization engine to ON
(checked).
Once I checked this field, all nodes are started to work.

Answer (score 2):

On CPU Settings on Set "Enable Virtualized CPU Performance Counter"
[image]